# convert query to IF EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, exists

How can this following code be converted to `IF EXISTS` ? So would like to return the ic.min values where it is less than c.min and c.geolevel=ic.study_geolevel and ic.[geog]=c.[geog]

```
select ic.[min]   
from [dbo].[ICov] ic,  
[dbo].[cov]  c
where 
    ic.[geog]=c.[geog] and 
    c.geolevel=ic.study_geolevel AND 
    c.min<ic.min
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  ic.[min]
FROM    [dbo].[ICov] AS ic
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM   [dbo].[cov] AS c 
                WHERE  ic.[geog]  = c.[geog] AND
                       c.geolevel = ic.study_geolevel AND 
                       c.min < ic.min)
```